# How to convert jQuery functions (that watch css classes) to usable code in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

Here is the jQuery code to watch the navbar in order to open and close it on click:

```
  $('#sidenav-toggle').on('click', function() {
    var $sidenav, $this;
    $this = $(this);
    $sidenav = $('.sidenav-overlay');
    if ($this.hasClass('open')) {
      $this.removeClass('open');
      return $sidenav.removeClass('open');
    } else {
      $this.addClass('open');
      return $sidenav.addClass('open');
    }
  });
  $('.sidenav-overlay').find('button.close').on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().removeClass('open');
    return $('#sidenav-toggle').removeClass('open');
  });
```

I'm not sure how to use this in Vue 3 though. I know I should probably use watchers to achieve the same functionality but I'm not sure how to actually write that code with the proper syntax in regards to CSS classes especially. I feel like I'm missing something very basic so I apologize if this is a stupid question, I would really appreciate some help. Thanks!

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I have been looking at this https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html. But I'm not sure where insert it. I think watchers wouldn't even be necessary, it could be done with 2 methods. My question now is more so how do I change css classes from a method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a class to hold your application state isn't the best idea really. In Vue, I would suggest having a data property that holds the state of whether the sidenav is open or not. You can then bind an event to the element which toggles the sidebar to toggle that property like so `v-bind:click="open = !open"`. Finally bind the class on the sidenav like so `v-bind:class="{open}"` which will apply the class `open` whenever the data property `open` is true.

I have created a codesandbox to showcase this. https://codesandbox.io/s/epic-sun-5vtm6

If you click on the Vue logo you can see the sidenav toggle in and out. Notice I have defined open in the component's data properties. The img tag has the event binding which toggles the value of of that open data property. The aside element then has the class binding which toggles the class on and off based on the value of the open property.